# Business owned in MS Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

Recently I been studying the entity ownership in MS Dynamics CRM where I came across "business owned" which doesn't give any detail further. upon the other two ownership like "organization owned" & "user/team owned" these two options are available during entity creation.

I am assuming that when "user/team" or "organization" uses security roles which is configured based on the business unit, as user/team are part of the Business Unit they are consider as "Business owned"

I referred the below link,
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309396.aspx#Anchor_3

1. so what is business owned?
2. when can a record be business owned?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is right.

Think that `OwnershipType` dropdown as a global optionset but only **Organization** & **User/Team** choices available for us. But the other 2 choices **Business** & **None** used by product internally & hidden for us.

Also `owningbusinessunit` populate based on owning user/team, decides if that record has to be shown to user based on the security role privilege (BU level) viz **filteredview**, record list, Retrieve, etc

> After you have chosen Entity ownership type of user/team, CRM will create some additional fields to enable the records to be owned by users/teams.
>
> It creates fields for OwningUser, OwningTeam, owningbusinessunit and ownerid.
>
> You have to record the business unit of the user/team so the security role can work out what other users can view the record.

[Read more](https://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/crm-entity-ownership-how-do-you-decide/)

Answer (score 0):

There is Business Unit in CRM which is under Organization so if any role has privilege Business Unit owned it means that Roles can work only on the data of that Business Unit where as any Roles having Organization Owned can work on any data on that Tenant.